# React - get the first node of a component?

Tags: reactjs

If i have a component like the following:

```
const MyComp = () => (
   <div> 
     <span> ... </span>
     <p> ... </p>
   </div>
)
```

And i have a function that takes `MyComp` as an argument, is it possible for that function to access its first element (in this example it's a `div`, but it could be any other element) so it could add an attribute to it?

Comment: You have a function that takes a function that returns a JSX element? Why not pass the desired attribute into the `MyComp` function and add it before returning the JSX element?

Comment: This is a behaviour required in my repo that currently contains 100 of such `MyComp` components. Instead of refactoring all of their usages in the repo and add a new prop, i want to create a HOC.

Comment: Why not using `ref`?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi in what way?

Comment: What attribute you want to add, please provide full example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), do you want to add a style? Make a wrapper, do you want to add actual prop? You can't. What is the usecase?

Comment: Not a style, a custom attribute, to have a result like `<div something="bla"> ... </div>`. I thought it wasn't going to be possible this way, but figured i'd ask anyway, maybe there's a way i'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. You can't have `MyComp` component and add an attribute to `div` element **without passing a `prop` or even a `ref`**.

In those scenarios, you should add another wrapper element and apply those attributes to it.

```
export default function Wrapper({children}) {
  return (
    <div data-value="5">
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

<Wrapper>
  <MyComp/>
</Wrapper>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought, just wanted to make sure there was really no other way.. oh well. Thanks!